# Different forms for different product types in Virtuemart?

Tags: forms, joomla, virtuemart

is there a way or component or plugin for Virtuemart which can help me build different types of forms used for different types of products?

For example, if I wish to buy a book I would like to have form A and if I wish to buy tool I would like to have form B shown and that particular form needs to be filled by customer.

Thanks in advance,

Deveti Putnik

Comment: Are you speaking of the checkout form or the product details form?

Comment: I am speaking of the checkout form.

Answer (score 0):

I think breezing forms and the virtuemart plugin from polished geek will help you
See here>
https://polishedgeek.com/free-extensions/virtuemart-breezing-forms-plugin/overview-a-features.html
and the breezing forms extension>
http://crosstec.de/joomla-forms-download.html

Goodluck